# HTML how to structure form-groups and bootstrap classes to catch single form data, pass to Python Flask

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, post, flask

I have a "GET" / "POST" split on my html page courtesy of a python flask script:

```
def home(name=None):
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('home.html', name=name)
if request.method == "POST":
    files = request.form["file[]"]
    do things with the files
```

On my home.html page, I have added in some bootstrap code to make everything pretty, but the flask module is now not taking in the form data properly. Here's my html code:

```
<form id="uploadbanner" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{ url_for('home') }}">

<div class="form-group">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    <br>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-s-6 col-xs-12">
            <h4>File Control</h4>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                And my form data is here:
                <input type="file" name="file[]" id="inputnameid" multiple=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        Second Column
        </div>
        New Row, etc etc
```

Each new row has buttons and inputs that I want to match with the form data using the name field.
 
I know I'm not structuring this properly, but I can't seem to find any info on how to mesh bootstrap and forms.

Answer (score 2):

I think in order to get the files, you should use `request.files["file[]"]` instead of `request.form["file[]"]` .